# Is there a way to create a function to convert to pandas?

Tags: json, pandas, function, dataframe

Im trying to create a function to convert a json to a dataframe. 
When i write it line by line it works

```
json_data = requests.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json')

text_data = json.loads(json_data.text)

data = pd.DataFrame(text_data)
```

I then created this function:

```
def JSON_to_DF(json):
    json_data = requests.get(json)
    print(type(json_data))
    text_data = json.loads(json_data.text)
    pd_data = pd.DataFrame(text_data)
    return pd_data
```

but when i run it it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

What part am I getting wrong?

Comment: Your function argument is called json, same as the module. Try renaming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two `json` in your function, one is a package, one is the variable. You should change the name of the variable:

```
# change the variable name here
def JSON_to_DF(json_str):
    json_data = requests.get(json_str)
    print(type(json_data))
    text_data = json.loads(json_data.text)
    pd_data = pd.DataFrame(text_data)
    return pd_data
```